# Faking Http Context with Moq and Mvc

Tags: moq

I’m trying to fake http context to test a Controller. My environment is MVC 3 and Moq 4.
So far I have tried a few options including:

a.

```
var searchController = new MySearchController(_mockResolver.Object.Resolve<IConfiguration>());
var mockContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
searchController.ControllerContext = mockContext.Object;
var result = searchController.Render();
```

b.

```
var searchController = new MopSearchController(_mockResolver.Object.Resolve<IConfiguration>());
searchController.MockControllerContext();
var result = searchController.Render();

public static class MockHttpHelper
{
    public static Mock<HttpContextBase> MockControllerContext(
                                this Controller controller, string path = null)
    {
        var mockHttpCtx = MockHttpHelper.MockHttpContext(path);
        var requestCtx = new RequestContext(mockHttpCtx.Object, new RouteData());
        var controllerCtx = new ControllerContext(requestCtx, controller);
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerCtx;
        return mockHttpCtx;
    }

    public static Mock<HttpContextBase> MockHttpContext(string path)
    {
        var mockHttpCtx = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var mockReq = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

        mockReq.SetupGet(x => x.RequestType).Returns("GET");
        mockReq.SetupGet(req => req.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        mockReq.SetupGet(req => req.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());

        mockHttpCtx.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(mockReq.Object);

        return mockHttpCtx;
    }
}
```

Neither of these work, I get the exception below. Can anyone point me in the direction of a working example? I’ve seen quite a few questions on the net around the same topic, but given the date (posts from 2008-2010) and MVC version (i.e. 1 and 2) I feel like I’m missing something / or trying to mock more than I need to in MVC3.

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.Mvc.ChildActionValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel(TModel model)
```

Thanks

Comment: i'ved added this to option a: var formValues = new FormCollection();
mycontroller.ValueProvider = formValues.ToValueProvider(); This works, but my controller action is GET so i shouldn't need a form collection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you were really missing, as you've noted, was setting the Controller's `ValueProvider`. Even though you're using this controller with a Get action but no Post action, the Controller still gets its `ValueProvider` instantiated upon creation, so you need to do the same thing in your test scenario. Here's the base class that I use when testing my controllers. I use [NBehave's NUnit wrapper](http://nuget.org/packages/nbehave.spec.nunit/) for unit testing, so ignore the `SpecBase` reference if you wish

```
public abstract class MvcSpecBase<T> : SpecBase<T> where T : Controller
{
    protected T Controller { get; set; }

    protected string RelativePath = string.Empty;

    protected string AbsolutePath = string.Empty;

    protected void InitialiseController(T controller, NameValueCollection collection, params string[] routePaths)
    {
        Controller = controller;
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        var httpContext = ContextHelper.FakeHttpContext(RelativePath, AbsolutePath, routePaths);
        var context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), Controller);
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), routes);
        Controller.ControllerContext = context;
        Controller.ValueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(collection, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        Controller.Url = urlHelper;
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, create your controller and then call this line:

```
InitialiseController(controller, new FormCollection());
```